# row view behaviour not the same when used in another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a row view where the row selection does work. I have a disclosure group that displays an exercise which contains equipment. In the row view, when I click an individual equipment, the behaviour works as expected. When I click on on an individual equipment, there appears a checkmark for the clicked equipment.

When I use the row view in another view, when I click an individual equipment, all the equipment for the exercise get a checkmark. I can't seem to figure out why this behaviour is occurring.

```
struct AddExerciseToTemplateSheetRow: View {
    
    let exercise: Exercise
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        DisclosureGroup {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                ForEach(exercise.equipment, id: \.self) { equipmentName in
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            viewModel.addEquipment(exerciseID: exercise.id ?? "", equipmentName: equipmentName)
                            
                            print(viewModel.isSelected)
                            
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                
                                Text(equipmentName)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                Divider()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if let selectedEquipment = viewModel.isSelected[exercise.id ?? ""], selectedEquipment.contains(equipmentName) {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: {
            
            HStack {
                Text(exercise.name)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Text(exercise.muscleGroup)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AddExerciseToTemplateSheet: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.exercise) { exercise in
                        AddExerciseToTemplateSheetRow(exercise: exercise, viewModel: viewModel)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(CustomColor.systemGray5)
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .tint(CustomColor.cyan)
                .onAppear {
                    
                    viewModel.fetchData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ExerciseViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var exercise = [Exercise]()
    //@Published var isSelected: [String: [String]] = [:]
    @Published var isSelected: [String: Set<String>] = [:]
    @Published var templateName = ""
    @Published var showSheet: Bool = false
    @Published var setCount: Int = 1
    
    func fetchData() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("exercises").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.exercise = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Exercise? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Exercise.self)
            }
            
            self.exercise.sort { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending }
        }
    }
    
    func addEquipment(exerciseID: String, equipmentName: String) {
        if isSelected[exerciseID] == nil {
            isSelected[exerciseID] = []
        }
        isSelected[exerciseID]?.toggle(equipmentName)
    }
    
    //    func addEquipment(exerciseID: String, equipmentName: String) {
    //
    //        if var selectedEquipment = isSelected[exerciseID] {
    //            if let index = selectedEquipment.firstIndex(of: equipmentName) {
    //
    //                selectedEquipment.remove(at: index)
    //
    //            } else {
    //
    //                selectedEquipment.append(equipmentName)
    //            }
    //
    //            isSelected[exerciseID] = selectedEquipment
    //
    //        } else {
    //
    //            isSelected[exerciseID] = [equipmentName]
    //        }
    //    }
}
```